# Show external links without Addressbar and open in modal view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, url, hide-elements

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Is it possible using Jquery to show an external link within SharePoint.

Wherein user clicks and it opens the external link in modal view with no address bar, so user doesn't get to know for the page they are accessing is part of another site.

Comment: Should you provide us more clarification , Are you need to show external link in SharePoint modal pop up? or you need only to show external link within a SharePoint page to hide the external URL !

Comment: Lpoling for both options.Modal pop up

Comment: Sorry for typo error. Looking for both options. Preference modal pop up, if not then opening the link with no address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all,** you should be aware of if the publisher doesn't [**allow to display its content in Iframe**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/#This-Content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame), you will not be able to show it inside SharePoint.

**Otherwise,** you will be able to open an External URL using [**SP.UI.ModalDialog**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/#SP.UI.ModalDialog-Options) SharePoint Modal Dialog.

> Please, check the details at **[Open a link via Modal Dialog in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint)**

---

**[Update]**

In case, you would like to use `Jquery`, so you can use `Fancy box` as Iframe, I think this link may help you to **[Use JQuery to show Modal Popup Per Session In SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/load-fancybox-popup-in-first-load-of-sharepoint-site/)**

Comment: Thanks, can u suggest that would allow to view the external link without url. I'm looking for javascript or jquery script.

Comment: the above is javascript and I also attached jquery , should you tell me what you need specifically , I only tried to help you :) and I think the above answer is at least useful and near to your question as you typed :)